Getting errors while upgrading from 2.4.6-p2 to 2.4.7-p1 (Could not find a magento/project package matching "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.6")
Hello guys i have Magento Adobe Commerce 2.4.6-p2 installed and i want to update to Adobe Commerce 2.4.7-p1 but when i try to run this command

composer require-commerce magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.7-p1
--no-update

to upgrade it says:

Could not find a magento/project package matching
"magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.6"

i dont know why this is happening. please help.

I just had a similar situation with upgrading from 2.4.7 to 2.4.7-p1 on a Community Edition instance.
I bypassed the issue by manually updating composer.json in the project root directory like this:
"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7-p1"
    },

and running
composer update

In your instance just change it to magento/product-enterprise-edition.
I'd recommend backing up your codebase before attempting this though.

In the composer.json file
change
"version": "2.4.6-p2" to "2.4.7-p1"
"magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": "2.4.6", to "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": "2.4.7",

Then run composer update command.

in my case

magento/magento-cloud-metapackage

was the issue
i have updated

"magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.4.6 <2.4.7"

to

"magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.4.7 <2.4.8"

thanks for your answer it helps alot.

